# Padding pandas columns with NaNs if offset is too large

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have some pandas Series containing booleans, and another Series that contains data values with the same index as the boolean Series (monthly data since a little after 1960).  I'm trying to create a DataFrame where the column name is the date where a `True` value was found in the `boolean_array`, and the column itself contains a window of values from `idx-offset` to `idx+offset`.  However, in the case where the offset would give an out of bounds error, I would like to pad the column with `NaN`s.

```
df = get_data() # DataFrame w/ time series data
boolean_array = create_bool_array() # time series of booleans

data_dict = {}
offset = 3

for val in np.where(boolean_array == True)[0]:
    idx = np.asscalar(val)
    dt = df.index[idx]
    if (idx - offset < 0):
        # pad w/ (offset - idx) NaNs at beginning of col
    if (idx + offset) > len(log_stock_returns):
        # pad w/ (offset + idx) - len(log_stock_returns) NaNs at end of col

    # This what I can use assuming there are no out of bounds errors
    data_dict[dt] = df['data_column'][idx-offset:idx+offset].values
```

Is there a simple way to do this in pandas or numpy?

**EDIT**: Example input and output with

```
df:                               boolean_array:
Date            data_column       Date          Value
---------------------------       -------------------
2013-01-01      55.0              2013-01-01    False
2013-02-01      57.0              2013-02-01    True
2013-03-01      52.0              2013-03-01    False
2013-04-01      56.0              2013-04-01    False
2013-05-01      59.0              2013-05-01    False
2013-06-01      61.0              2013-06-01    False
2013-07-01      63.0              2013-07-01    True
2013-08-01      66.0              2013-08-01    True
2013-09-01      67.0              2013-09-01    False
2013-10-01      67.0              2013-10-01    False
2013-11-01      69.0              2013-11-01    True
2013-12-01      70.0              2013-12-01    False

data_dict (output) with offset = 3
key: 2013-02-01, value: [NaN, NaN, 55.0, 57.0, 52.0, 56.0, 59.0]
key: 2013-07-01, value: [56.0, 59.0, 61.0, 63.0, 66.0, 67.0, 67.0]
key: 2013-08-01, value: [59.0, 61.0, 63.0, 66.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0]
key: 2013-11-01, value: [66.0, 67.0, 67.0, 69.0, 70.0, NaN, NaN]
```

Comment: pls show a copy-pastable example of the input (or a dummy creation of what it looks like), and an example of the output.

Comment: Will do, give me a few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best method, but it works (Python 2.7) ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from cStringIO import StringIO


PI_KWARGS = dict(freq='M', periods=7)

tseries_data = '''2013-01-01      55.0
2013-02-01      57.0
2013-03-01      52.0
2013-04-01      56.0
2013-05-01      59.0
2013-06-01      61.0
2013-07-01      63.0
2013-08-01      66.0
2013-09-01      67.0
2013-10-01      67.0
2013-11-01      69.0
2013-12-01      70.0'''

bool_col = '''2013-01-01    False
 2013-02-01    True
 2013-03-01    False
 2013-04-01    False
 2013-05-01    False
 2013-06-01    False
 2013-07-01    True
 2013-08-01    True
 2013-09-01    False
 2013-10-01    False
 2013-11-01    True
 2013-12-01    False'''


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tseries_data), index_col=0, parse_dates=True, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Date', 'Data'])
bools = pd.read_csv(StringIO(bool_col), index_col=0, parse_dates=True, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Date', 'Data'])
dates = bools.where(bools).dropna().index

def make_back_datetime_index(time, nmonths=3, **pi_kwargs):

    month = time.month - nmonths % 12
    is_month = month > 0

    nyears = int(nmonths) / 12 + (not is_month)
    month = (is_month and month) or 12 + month
    start = pd.datetime(time.year - nyears, month, time.day)

    return pd.PeriodIndex(start=start, **pi_kwargs).to_datetime()

data_dict = {date : df.ix[make_back_datetime_index(date, **PI_KWARGS)] for date in dates}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use concat and set the axis to 1...

```
df = pd.concat([df, boolean_array], axis=1)
```

Comment: At what point in the code would I do this?  I don't understand exactly how this solves my problem.

Comment: after you have generated your df dataframe with the data column and your Series boolean_array with the value feature.

Comment: Yeah, that will create a new DataFrame with my two Series side-by-side, but I don't think it solves the problem I'm asking about with NaN padding.

Comment: it automatically gives NaN padding (outer join) if you set parameter join to inner, it would give no padding.

Comment: Yeah I know it gives NaN padding, but only on the indices the joining is done over.  I'm trying to select `[idx-offset:idx+offset]` where each `idx` is the date that's `True` in the `boolean_array`.  Would you mind expanding on your answer?  I still don't think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I am confused about what you want as an output - maybe put an actual dataframe output in your question.  Are you talking about shifting the values that are true? df[df['value']].shift()

Comment: I want to create a `dict` with dates as keys, and Series of values as values.  If offset were 5, then I would want each Series to be 5 values before each `True` is found through 5 values after each `True` is found.  However, if I find a `True` that's less than 5 away from the beginning or end of the boolean array, then I want to pad the values that can't be found with `NaN`s.